# Azure devops pipeline - Visual studio build step - How to precompile cshtml views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, azure-devops

We have a devops setup in which we use the "Visual studio build step" to build our solution. I have searched high and low to find out how to ensure that our cshtml views are precompiled as part of the build task, but I haven't found a solution.

Our solution is standard .Net 4.7.2 using MVC.

Our build step looks as below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add  **`/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true`** to MSBuild Arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)" /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true
```