# Azure Devops - how to precompile Asp.Net Framework MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, msbuild

I have inherited a couple of Asp.Net 4.8 MVC websites that I am building and deploying using Azure Devops Pipelines. Each page is very slow to start up the first time each one is hit, so I want to precompile them.

Following the advice in this SO question:

[Azure devops pipeline - Visual studio build step - How to precompile cshtml views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759793/azure-devops-pipeline-visual-studio-build-step-how-to-precompile-cshtml-view)

I add `/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true"` to the MsBuild parameters.

However, like one of the comments on there, that gives me the following build error:

`[error]Project\obj\release\aspnetcompilemerge\source\web.config(52,0): Error ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`

A reply suggested adding the following to the MsBuild parameters:

`/p:BaseIntermediateOutputPath=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\tmp_obj\`

This, however, then gave me hundreds of errors along the lines of:

`Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Which has rather left me flummoxed.

Both sites compile and run fine in VS2019, however I can recreate the issue locally by running MsBuild using Powershell:

```
Invoke-MsBuild -Path "solution.sln" -MsBuildParameters "/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False /p:PackageLocation=\Users\name\code\repofolder\packages\\ /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:BaseIntermediateOutputPath=\tmp_obj\\"
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here?